# Drupal 8 - How to know if the checkbox belonging to a Checkbox Label is checked?

Tags: twig, drupal-8

In Drupal 8, I am trying to add a class to a Checkbox Label only if the corresponding checkbox is checked. I am assuming I would have some kind of logic in **form-element-label.html.twig** to first ensure it is a checkbox label and then some how get at the checkbox to see if the attribute of 'checked' exists.

I can't get this to work and haven't been able to find a solution on the internet, so I am asking here. Apologies for I am a .NET developer and feel like something this simple should be easy to do but I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

A preprocess function on form element perhaps.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['type'] === 'checkbox' && $variables['element']['#checked']) {
    $variables['label']['#attributes']['class'] = ['ckecbox-is-checked'];
  }
}
```